# sql criteria with count function aliasToBean issue Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

In my sql i have used count function like

```
COUNT( bip.seat_number) as totalSeats
```

Im trying to map this totalSeats attribute to a java bean called ScheduleSummery

```
Transformers.aliasToBean(ScheduleSummery.class)
```

Here is my java bean class

```
public class ScheduleSummery {

    private String totalSeats;
public String getTotalSeats() {
        return totalSeats;
    }
    public void setTotalSeats(String totalSeats) {
        this.totalSeats = totalSeats;
    }
}
```

Im getting below exception when trying to run this code. I have defined totalSeats as a String but it still shows expected type as java.lang.String

```
 IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property 
[ScheduleSummery.totalSeats 
(expected type = java.lang.String)]; 
target = [ScheduleSummery@3f08662f], property value = [27]
```

any idea ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your query returns some kind of number and your property is expecting a String.

You have to options

1. convert the result of the query to a String like so (should work with Oracle, the precise syntax for other databases might vary):

   ```
   to_char(COUNT( bip.seat_number)) as totalSeats
   ```
2. change the property to the type you are getting out of the sql statement. You already tried int (according to other, now deleted answers. Other options you might try are: `long, Long, Integer, BigInteger` If try and error doesn't help, you can determine where in the code Hibernate tries the assignement (from the stacktrace), put a breakpoint there and see, what kind of value it actually has.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It worked. Correct syntax for mysql is convert( COUNT( bip.seat_number) ,char(10)) as totalSeats